# East and West German Chess

Tags: rating, history, fide

Interested in chess history, I wonder if there is an accessible data set that lists all players from East and West Germany in the 80's, ideally with information like the FIDE website (name, national Elo rating, gender and year of birth). I would also be interested in the same data for Germany in the 90s and 2000s.

Note 1. Wikipedia lists I know are too sparse ([East German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:East_German_chess_players) or [German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:German_chess_players) players).

Note 2. @BrianTower's answer is very useful but I'm afraid that by focusing only on FIDE players I would miss good players who were not FIDE rated because of the old rating floors for men (2205) and women (2005).

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder if there is an accessible data set that lists all players
> from East and West Germany in the 80's

The [Olimpbase](https://www.olimpbase.org/index.php) site has a [downloadable zip file of FIDE rating data from 1967 to 2001](https://www.olimpbase.org/Elo/data/elo1967-2001.zip). It is accessible in the sense that you can download it but the data you want would have to be extracted from the dataset which isn't in an easily readable form. It is also quite "dirty".

Now I have already done this so for me it is just a matter of executing the right sql command. Here are the results for East German players. Note that FIDE Ids came in just as the GDR ceased to exist so some of the players don't have proper FINs. Nevertheless my DB requires a unique FIN for each player so the shorter FINs were either the 5-digit, one-year FINs which FIDE created initially before they thought maybe they should cater for more than 100,000 players or they were auto-constructed by my load program.

FullName    FIDEID  DoBYear Sex MaxRating
Apel, Stefan 4612116 1969    M   2265
Aring, Gerd  4665791 1963    M   2230
Babrikowski, Peter, Dr.  4611942 1956    M   2320
Bade, Heidrun    4612710 1945    F   2040
Barth, Rainer    4611918 1958    M   2280
Bauer, Reinhard, Dr. 4611772 1954    M   2310
Baum, Bernd, Dr. 4611853 1945    M   2265
Baumbach, Friedrich, Dr. 4611721 1935    M   2460
Becker, Michael  4611667 1957    M   2330
Belke, Frank, Dr.    4612337 1963    M   2230
Beltz, Martina   4612485 1962    F   2160
Besser, Hans 4601033 1935    M   2460
Birke, Andreas   4612140 1966    M   2255
Boehlig, Heinz, Dr.  4614283 1943    M   2450
Boehnisch, Manfred   4611543 1941    M   2390
Boensch, Uwe 4611268 1958    M   2575
Boettcher, Ilse  17753   NULL    F   2045
Bonsch, Uwe  17771   NULL    M   2505
Borriss, Martin, Dr. 4611950 1970    M   2300
Brameyer, Hermann    4612019 1939    M   2270
Braun, Gottfried, Dr.    4611489 1933    M   2400
Braun, Regine    4612744 1954    F   1910
Broeder, Iris    4612426 1962    F   2225
Broemel, Richard 4612256 1958    M   2240
Bromel, Richard  78522   NULL    M   2240
Brueggemann, Joachim 4611861 1951    M   2365
Bueder, Thomas   4612183 1967    M   2260
Burchardt, Brigitte  4612213 1954    F   2295
Camin, Gesine    17844   NULL    F   2020
Casper, Thomas   4611403 1959    M   2435
Csulits, Anton   4611705 1942    M   2345
Daemering, Katrin    4612604 1966    F   2100
Dietze, Wolfgang, Dr.    4611802 1950    M   2340
Enders, Peter    4611314 1963    M   2490
Espig, Gesine    4612523 1959    F   2135
Espig, Lutz  4611276 1949    M   2490
Espig, Thomas    4612027 1954    M   2380
Feibert, Petra   4606191 1958    F   2255
Feustel  18116   NULL    M   2305
Frommelt, Hans-Juergen   4612159 1954    M   2255
Fuchs, Reinhart  4611357 1934    M   2460
Gaffron, Petra   18169   NULL    F   1820
Gauglitz, Gernot 4611365 1962    M   2480
Gautzsch, Christina  4612620 NULL    F   1980
Geibler, G.  18204   NULL    F   2055
Geissler, Grit   4612655 1967    F   2050
Goehler, Antje   4612469 1967    F   2220
Goldberg, Alexander, Dr. 4611560 1965    M   2340
Golz, Werner 18253   1933    M   2410
Grigorov 18292   NULL    M   2205
Grottke, Hans-Joachim, Dr.   4612167 1942    M   2280
Gruenberg, Hans-Ulrich   4611306 1956    M   2510
Hackel, Mario    4611780 1970    M   2360
Harnisch, Diana  4612531 NULL    F   2025
Hartlapp, Jutta  4612612 NULL    F   1985
Heinatz, Dr. Gundula 4612434 1969    F   2195
Heinatz, Thomas  4611748 1965    M   2355
Heinen   18363   NULL    M   2265
Heinig, Wolfram, Dr. 4611926 1954    M   2365
Heinsohn, Guenther   4641140 1945    M   2235
Heinsohn, Wilfried   4612400 1947    M   2215
Heintze, Marion  4612191 1954    F   2235
Hennings, Artur  4611594 1940    M   2475
Hesse, Peter 4611519 1944    M   2440
Hobusch, Cornelia    4612574 1960    F   2000
Hoeckendorf, Hartmut 4612302 1954    M   2255
Hoelzlein, Christina 18391   1951    F   2140
Hoffmann, Helga  4608933 1932    F   2015
Hoffmann, R. 18392   NULL    F   2205
Hofmann, B.  18393   NULL    F   2230
Jahn, Constanze  4612450 1963    F   2210
Jahnel, Guenther 4636147 1958    M   2315
Jakat, Thomas    4612329 1959    M   2270
Janssen, Lieselotte  4612515 1937    F   2040
Jaster, Robert, Prof. Dr.    4612418 1964    M   2225
Jeske, Eckhard   4641485 1952    M   2235
Jeske, Kirsten   4612728 1963    F   2025
Just, Gabriele, Dr.  4612558 1936    F   2155
Kaminski, Uwe    4611381 1962    M   2405
Keller, Manfred  4607368 1945    M   2325
Keller-Hermann, Edith    4611870 1921    F   2190
Kestler, Hans-Guenther   4601076 1939    M   2450
Kimpinsky, Frank 4611934 1960    M   2300
Kleeschaetzky, Rainer    4611985 1963    M   2290
Kliefoth, Christel   4612752 1957    F   1880
Kluss, C.    18592   NULL    F   1880
Knaak, Rainer    4611250 1953    M   2565
Kobe, U. 18597   NULL    M   2270
Kobe, Ulrich 4612035 1941    M   2270
Kopfer, Michael  89915   NULL    M   2235
Kosowski, Todor  4612310 1970    M   2235
Kroggel, Rita    18658   NULL    F   1840
Krug, Peter  18662   NULL    M   2220
Kube, Hannelore  4612760 1953    F   2005
Kunze, Kerstin   4612493 1971    F   2215
Kyas, Juergen    4618157 1955    M   2230
Lamm, Steffen    4612175 1963    M   2280
Lang, Jens, Dr.  4611756 1960    M   2315
Lehmann, Christina   4612442 1951    F   2075
Lenk, Wolfgang   4612388 1938    M   2250
Liebert, Heinz   4611438 1936    M   2485
Litkiewicz, Kurt 4612264 1934    M   2240
Lorenz, Gerd 4612272 1944    M   2275
Luther, Thomas   4611420 1969    M   2425
Malich, Burkhard, Dr.    4611330 1936    M   2535
Manger, Carola   12092   1959    F   2110
Meissner, Hans-Juergen   4611969 1953    M   2290
Melzer, Monika   4612680 NULL    F   1940
Mevissen, Ulrich 4612736 1938    F   2025
Moehring, Guenther   4611462 1936    M   2450
Mueller, K.  18988   NULL    F   1870
Mueller, Klaus   4611578 1942    M   2470
Mueller, Werner  4612370 1954    M   2215
Mueller, Werner  18992   NULL    M   2205
Neukirch, Detlef 4611624 1940    M   2375
Nobis, Martina   4612779 1959    F   2005
Nowarra, Waltraud    4612361 1940    F   2120
Nuenchert, Eveline   4612540 1943    F   2145
Oetzel, Roland   4612043 NULL    M   2270
Okrajek, Alexander   4612221 1956    M   2230
Pachow, Joerg    4612230 1961    M   2255
Packroff, Hermann    4611896 1941    M   2290
Paehtz, Thomas   4611349 1956    M   2515
Petigk, Falk 4611373 1930    M   2420
Pfeil, Hartmut   4611810 1951    M   2300
Pfretzschner, Roland 4612086 1958    M   2265
Poldauf, Dirk    4611470 1965    M   2390
Pollak, Georg    4611551 1946    M   2350
Postler, Reinhard    4611608 1944    M   2375
Pranner, Marion  4612582 NULL    F   1990
Prussas, Claudia 19262   NULL    F   1835
Raitza, Olaf 4611675 1934    M   2325
Ramseier, Jana S.    1302329 1969    F   2080
Riecks, A.   19343   NULL    F   1805
Roesch, Arnd, Prof.  4611632 1965    M   2335
Roesler, Matthias, Dr.   4611977 1966    M   2270
Rosenthal, Dirk  4611586 1970    M   2280
Rossmann, Helmut 4612094 1956    M   2360
Rozental, D. 19388   NULL    M   2305
Ruebensam, Helmut    4612051 1955    M   2270
Schilar, Michael 19465   NULL    M   2225
Schmidt, Gerhard 4605233 1940    M   2275
Schneider, Frank 4612299 1945    M   2240
Schoene, Ralf    4611535 1961    M   2310
Schoeneberg, Manfred 4611845 1946    M   2470
Schurade, Matthias   4611497 1959    M   2385
Seidemann, Ulricke   4612639 1955    F   2080
Seils, Gudula    4612671 1961    F   2045
Seils, Joerg 4612078 1963    M   2255
Skibbe, Diana    4612698 1961    F   2040
Sommaro, Katja   4612590 1966    F   2135
Starck, Bodo 4611829 1934    M   2325
Starck, Ines 4612477 1963    F   2135
Stern, Rene  4611799 1972    M   2335
Stettler, Michael    4611454 1961    M   2375
Syre, Christian  4611993 1954    M   2285
Teske, Henrik    4611500 1968    M   2425
Thal, Olaf   4611683 1935    M   2355
Thormann, Wolfgang   4611713 1949    M   2360
Tischbierek, Raj 4611322 1962    M   2500
Uhlmann, Wolfgang    4611284 1935    M   2590
Vogt, Lothar 4611292 1952    M   2520
Volke, Karsten   4611411 1965    M   2395
Wagner-Michel, Annett    4612205 1955    F   2230
Walter, Guenter  4612108 1942    M   2370
Weyrich, Morten  4611659 1959    M   2290
Wieland, Ilse    4612507 1957    F   2045
Wolf, Sylvia 4612701 1962    F   2025
Wolff, Sonja 19903   NULL    F   1815
Womacka, Mathias 4611390 1966    M   2395
Zahn, Juergen    4612345 1946    M   2225
Zinn, Lothar 19958   1938    M   2435

Running the same query for Germany gives almost 1100 rows which is too much to post here IMHO. If you can find a way you are happy with sending me an email address I can send you some bigger query results.

Comment: Thank you! It's very useful and I was able to download the data and launch a query. However, I'm afraid I would miss good players who are not FIDE rated because of the  rating floors for men (2205) and women (2005).